# VueJS: setInterval method not working properly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, setinterval

Please tell me what am i doing wrong? I want to active 'cloth' update every 2 sec. Still learning vue. Thanks

```
    data() {
        return {
            clothes: ['t-shirts', 'sneakers', 'jackets'],
            count: 0,
            cloth: ''
        }
    },
    methods: {
        startInterval() {
            setInterval(() => {

                this.cloth = this.clothes[this.count]
                this.count++
                if (this.count >= this.clothes.length) {
                    this.count = 0;
                }
            }, 2000)
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where you are executing `startInterval`?

Comment: Oh..That's right..It's working if im adding event click with startInterval. But how make this func self running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vue has a life cycle that you can leverage to complete this objective. You can hook into the `created` function and execute your interval within:

```
created() {
    this.startInterval()
},
```

This is `not` a method. It will be a `sibling` to your `data` and `method` properties.

Comment: Thanks! It helped